# what is "isKindOfClass" and why we use it?

Tags: objective-c

What this chunk of code mean?

```
[images isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]
```

Its return an boolean but why we use it?

Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html

Comment: Please read the docs before asking such questions.

Comment: It might not be terribly useful in the simple example you provide, but it's very helpful in circumstances where you might have different types of objects returned (e.g. parsing JSON which can return a `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` and you need to know what was returned).

Comment: @Zenith: That appears to cover everything except why you might want to use it.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with Xcode?

Comment: Objective c is quite verbose in its method naming conventions. You should be able to make a good educated guess about what this might do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`isKindOfClass`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) returns true when an object inherits from (or is) a given class. In this case, it's checking if `images` is a `NSArray` or a subclass of `NSArray`.

An example of usage in some code I'm working on is checking if the item we're displaying needs to be handled for an iPad (`[ctrl isKindOfClass:[BaseSplitViewController class]]`) or the iPhone. Like this:

```
CGRect backViewFrame = CGRectZero;
if ([currentController isKindOfClass:[BaseSplitViewController class]]) {
    //Set width and hight of background View to 1024.
    [backgroundView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1024)];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        backViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        backViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
    }
} else {
    backViewFrame = currentController.view.frame;
    [backgroundView setFrame:backViewFrame];
}
```

Comment: Why might you want to use it?

Comment: The check also sees if it is the same class, not only inherits.

Comment: @rmaddy whoops, clarified that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Updated with a code sample - took me a bit to find it.